# pcap_sendpacket will send two identical packets once

Tags: windows, network-programming, pcap, winpcap, npcap

I'm trying to send some self-packed Ethernet packets via the Winpcap API pcap_sendpacket(), but I got two identical packets after invoking the API once. The two packets can be captured on Wireshark for debugging purpose, with identical data and continuous frame numbers.

The environment is Win7 64bit. And it is wierd that the same code base running on another Win7 64bit will show only one packet on Wireshark.

Edit:

[2016.1.24 19:30]

I'm sorry I can only post the pcap related code parts due to the confidential thing

```
// first, enum the device list
pcap_if_t *m_alldevs;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
if (pcap_findalldevs(&m_alldevs, errbuf) == -1)
{
    // log error ...

for(pcap_if_t *d = m_alldevs; d != NULL; d = d->next)
{


// second, open the interface
// use flag PCAP_OPENFLAG_MAX_RESPONSIVENESS to get response quickly
// set timeout to 1000ms
errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
pcap_t* fp = pcap_open(d->name, 65536, PCAP_OPENFLAG_PROMISCUOUS|PCAP_OPENFLAG_MAX_RESPONSIVENESS, 1000, NULL, errbuf);


// third, get the interface device then release all the device
pcap_freealldevs(m_alldevs);

// 4th, send data
// unsigned char* buf;
// int size;
pcap_sendpacket(fp, buf, size);
```

And for the packet, the packet is handcrafted, with size between 64 and 1500, has an IEEE 802.3 type frame header, the two mac fields are customized.

On the machine that has the error, the version of the Winpcap is "4.1.0.2980", Wireshark is "64bit 1.12.3"; I will check the other machine that does not have the error tomorrow.

Edit:

[2016.1.26 10:30]
The version of the Winpcap is "4.1.0.2980", the same as on the machine with error. The version of Wireshark is "64bit 1.12.8". Both OS are Win7 Enterprise 64bit.

Comment: It's rather hard to help pinpoint your problem if you don't show us the source code you used.

Comment: "And it is weird that the same code base running on another Win7 64bit will show only one packet on Wireshark."  Same version of Wireshark, with the same version of WinPcap, on both machines?

Comment: I have added some code parts and the comparison of the versions of Wireshark and WinPcap, hoping it will be more clear. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

My steps to resolve it:

1. uninstall `winpcap` & `npcap`. I have both on my local machine
2. install only `npcap`
3. use delayed dll loading according to https://nmap.org/npcap/guide/npcap-devguide.html section "For software that want to use Npcap first when Npcap and WinPcap coexist".